# What's the best way to get the main currency for a company using the QBO API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Using the QBO API how do I determine what currency the company is using in their QuickBooks file or overall as a company? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, chalk this up to not reading a little more into the docs, you can easily find this under the Company Preferences under "HomeCurrency", using the QBO api v3 you can find it under this url:

```
https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/realm_id_goes_here/preferences
```

And should see some json like this:

```
...
 "CurrencyPrefs": {
      "MultiCurrencyEnabled": false,
      "HomeCurrency": {
        "value": "USD"
      }
    },
....
```